# Adding additional data from server to existing restangular collection

Tags: angularjs, restangular

What is the right way to add more data in to an existing collection with Restanglar?

Currently on page load I am performing:

```
app.factory('Post', ['Restangular', function(Restangular) {
   return Restangular.service('posts');
}]);

var Posts = Post.getList({embed:'comments.replies,tags', limit:'50'}).$object;
$scope.posts = Posts;
```

This gets my initial bunch of posts nicely.

On the front end the user can then select a tag which filters the results, and I want to load up some more from the server for the specific tag. Currently I am replacing the existing posts with:

```
Posts = Post.getList({embed:'comments.replies,tags', limit:'100', tag:tag.name}).$object;
$scope.posts = Posts;
```

The data is coming back great from the API. What is the best practice way to push the data in to the exiting/original Restangular collection?

Ideally I want to keep adding to this collection, merging the result so that there are no dupes.

Is there a Restangular method that is used to merge as it seems a common use case. (Could be used for loading additional paginated data too.)

Comment: By the way, I must have promise, not just json, which server will returns to use restangular functions to work with collections.